# Angular Material datepicker manual open

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

In the datepicker documentation there is an example of the popup calendar being controlled programatically by using the `open()` and `close()` methods like so:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
```

One can also set the `opened` property to true/false like so:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.opened = true">Open</button>
```

I wonder if there is anyway to use this to get the calendar popup to stay permanently opened for the purpose of letting the user click around on different dates, and having those selection reflected in the input?

Comment: You can implement the dateChange emitter to reopen the the datepicker when a date is selected.

Comment: ehhh, I see.  Could you help me with some implementation details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you can try this :

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput (dateChange)="reOpenCalendar()" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
```

in your component ts/js file you need to declare a new method :

```
export class YourComponent{
   @ViewChild('picker') picker;
   //....
   reOpenCalendar(){
     let self = this;
        setTimeout(
            ()=>{                
                self.picker.open();
            },
            50
        );
   }
}
```

This will introduce a flash effect as the date picker disappears and quickly reappears.

The other solution would be fork angular material datepicker component in your local project and introduce an Input property to disable the closing when a date is selected

Comment: I applied the `dateChange()` emitter to the stackblitz example in the official docs and it still closes the popup when I select a date :/.  I wish the documentation was a little better...I did not even know there is a dateChange emitter.  Maybe I need an actual widget for this requirement rather than using Material's datepicker.

Comment: I moved the emitter to the input tag as that's where it should go. The timeout on the method is to allow Angular to execute its change detection on the date selected event and only then reopen the datepicker.

Comment: Ingenious!  Too bad about the flicker :(

Answer (score 1):

The built-in datepicker control of Material library comes with an internal Calendar component. You can use the following to have a calendar that is always open (without the input box but still works with date/month/year selection)

Read more about the calendar here:

https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-material-calendar-component/